# Drawing asymmetrical ellipses in HTML5 Canvas using js?

Tags: javascript, html, geometry

I've been trying to draw an asymmetrical ellipse using HTML5 Javascript,

My first try was using the arc and the scale but I was only able to generate symmetrical ellipses using that,

So my second try was using bezier curves. Which had as main problem that I don't understand how they work...

In the end, I ended up with something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/eLEUD/4/

It works, but I have the modifiers hardcoded in there, as soon as you change the points, it stops working. I have no idea how to calculate them though...

Who can help me further?

Comment: Why don't you try using a canvas library? This will make life much easier plus you don't need to handle the redrawing events?

Comment: I think you mean 'oval' not 'ellipse'. An egg, for example is an oval because it does not have a precise mathematical shape. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Oval.html

Comment: @shouvik If you can recommend a library that can solve this issue, I'll happily take a look at it.

Comment: @ChristopherTokar Thanks, yeah, I did meant an oval.

Comment: http://ocanvas.org/docs/Display-Objects/Ellipse

Comment: @Shouvik That does look like a nice library to use, however, unless I'm really not awake, I don't see support for asymmetrical ovals :(

Comment: hmmm, asymmetrical ovals are not supported by this library I think. Well in case I come across something I will sure link back here...

Answer (score 0):

The bezierCurveTo function actually draws the last three nodes of a [Cubic Bezier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)

Cubic bezier curves require 4 points to be drawn:

- P1: the starting point of the curve.
- P2: the first point the curve heads towards but does not touch.
- P3: the sencond point the curve heads towards but does not touch.
- P4: the end point of the curve.

Given that, the code looks like this (assuming P1,P2,P3,P4 are point structures):

```
//move to the first part of the curve
context.moveTo(P1.x, P1.y);
//draw the curve.
context.bezierCurveTo(P2.x, P2.y,
                  P3.x, P3.y,
                  P4.x, P4.y);
```

The bezierCurveTo function treats the whatever point the canvas context is sitting at as the first anchor point.

As for drawing your egg shape, you're just going to have to fiddle with it until you're happy with whatever shape you're looking for.

I hope that helps.

---

**EDIT**

It seems like maybe you're trying to draw an egg shape *inside* the diamond shape... so I've updated your fiddle to do that. See the green egg shape here:

http://jsfiddle.net/blesh/zVWrH/1/

What I did is calculate the other points around the diamond: northeast, north-by-northeast, etc. and used those as anchor points.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the bezier curves only 'head towards' the control points, it doesn't go through the points. I know the north, east, south and west point coordinates, but I need the oval to be actualy 'fill' that space. So the control points have to be calculated based on the information i have. I just don't know how to calculate them

Comment: Then what you need to do is use more curves, honestly. It will always go through the last set of coordinates for the function call... so P4.x and P4.y need to be the coordinates you want it to go through. Outside of that P2 and P3 are going to have to be points you fudge around with to get the curves the way you want them.

Comment: I did try more curves, but I can't get it look correct. Using 2, it looks alright but only with the hardcoded modifiers. If you can get it too look correctly using 4, then I'd love to know how.

Comment: Well you're going to have to have hard coded modifiers. What you're asking for is pretty subjective. For one thing there's no such thing as an "asymmetrical ellipse". I'm assuming you're trying to make some sort of egg shape, but there are all sorts of different egg shapes and only you'll know which one looks right to you. You'll just have to try many different configurations until you get it right.

Comment: Wait, do you mean, you want it to be *inside* that diamond shape?

Comment: Actualy, I meant the egg-shape should go through the coordinates specified, but very nicely done!

Comment: Well the fiddle you had was already going through your points... so what you want isn't something you can ask for here. You're going to have to fiddle with how your getting your curves on your own until you're happy with the outcome. I don't think anyone here is going to be able to help you.